# Установка Pygame в PyPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pypy

как мне установить `pygame` в pypy?

`pypy3 -m pip install pygame` - не работает

(работаю в ОС Manjaro Linux)

вот ислкючение:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/pypy3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-h2xcnivl/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-h2xcnivl/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-2_yep1kv
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-h2xcnivl/pygame/
    Complete output (26 lines):


WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using UNIX configuration...

/bin/sh: pkg-config: команда не найдена
/bin/sh: pkg-config: команда не найдена
/bin/sh: pkg-config: команда не найдена
/bin/sh: freetype-config: команда не найдена
/bin/sh: freetype-config: команда не найдена
/bin/sh: freetype-config: команда не найдена

Hunting dependencies...
WARNING: "pkg-config freetype2" failed!
WARNING: "freetype-config" failed!
SDL     : found 1.2.15
FONT    : found
IMAGE   : found
MIXER   : found
PNG     : found
JPEG    : found
SCRAP   : found
PORTMIDI: found
PORTTIME: found
FREETYPE: not found
Missing dependencies
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Как именно не работает? Где вывод ошибки?

Comment: @cauf поправил описание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вам стоит скачать бинарник модуля, после чего разместить его в папку проекта и установить локально. Если используете PyCharm - то через консоль IDE

Answer (score 2):

В самой нижней части вывода установки можно увидеть раздел `Hunting dependencies...` - это раздел поиска зависимостей в системе. Причем зависимостей не в виде модулей питона, а, судя по всему, системных пакетов. В этом разделе вначале идут строки с результатом `found`, то есть "найдено". А вот последняя из них `FREETYPE: not found`. Соответственно этой библиотеки, судя по всему, в системе не найдено.